# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void contains(String) from the type List<Lead>

Tags: apex, trigger, list

I'm trying to find if there's a duplicate record Name in Lead object if I create new record, however I'm getting this error when using contains() method. What can I do to fix this? And why I'm getting this error, "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void contains(String) from the type List".. when I'm using String parameter in contains() method?

```
   trigger LeadsTrigger on Lead (before insert) {       
        List<Lead> queryLeads = [SELECT Id, Name From Lead];
        for(Lead lead : trigger.new) {
            if(queryLeads.contains(lead.FirstName + ' ' + lead.LastName)) { 
                lead.addError('Name already exist.');                  
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking string in contains whereas type of your list if Lead.
Update code as below.

```
trigger LeadsTrigger on Lead (before insert) {       
    Set<String> leadNamesSet = new Set<String>();
    for(Lead queryLead : [SELECT Id, Name From Lead LIMIT 50000]) {
        leadNamesSet.add(queryLead.Name);
    }
    
    for(Lead lead : trigger.new) {
        if(leadNamesSet.contains(lead.FirstName + ' ' + lead.LastName)) { 
            lead.addError('Name already exist.');                  
        }
        leadNamesSet.add(lead.FirstName + ' ' + lead.LastName);
    }
}
```

If you will have more than 50,000 leads in the system then this solution will fail.
Ideal solution for this is to use [duplicate rules](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.duplicate_rules_map_of_reference.htm&type=5)

Comment: This won't work if the data has duplicates, code is only checking against existing records. where you add error, you must also fill the names for inserted records. Indeed duplicate rules is more scalable

Comment: @Raul Updated code with your suggestion.